# python3 module for importing xls files

Tags: excel, python-3.x, xls

Are there any python3 modules for importing(reading) excel .xls files or is there any work in progress on porting one of the python2 modules? All I'm coming up with is xlrd for python2.

Comment: Someone did have a go at porting xlrd to Python 3 - use it at your own risk: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd3

Answer (score 0):

I believe the maintainer of `xlrd` is working on porting it, but it's not yet ready.